# How can I unsubscribe from a any var observable in angular when component is destroyed?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

@Input()
var:any;

var passed as an observable but I'm getting a var.unsubscribe() is not a function when ngDestroyed is called.

I tried var.unsubscribe() and is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `async` pipe inside the template and avoid (as much as possible) subscribing inside the component.
if you must subscribe inside the component (.ts file) use the following approach for unsubscribing. don't do that inside services!

```
export class MyComponent {

   private readonly onDestroy = new Subject<void>();

   products$: Observable<Product>;

   constructor(private myService: MyService) { }
   
   ngOnInit(): void {
    
    // the right way
    // don't forget to use the async pipe inside the template
    this.products$ = this.myService.getMyProducts(); 


    // not the best way
    this.myService.getMyProducts().pipe(
      takeUntil(this.onDestroy),
      tap((products: Product) => {
         
         // do your staff
         
      })
    ).subscribe()

   }
   
   ngOnDestroy() {
     this.onDestroy.next();
     this.onDestroy.complete();
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

it's a pretty generic issue, you can find anywhere in google, like this article https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-takeuntil-rxjs-unsubscribe

you can either do stuff like

```
var.pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)).subscribe()
```

or you can assign it to subscriptions

```
this.sub = var.subscribe()
```

then later on in onDestroy do

```
this.sub.unsubscribe();
```

either way this article have good examples

Answer (score 1):

You do not `unsubscribe` an `observable`, but a `subscription`. `Observables` are `lazy`, unless you `subscribe` to them, they won't fire. You can simply `subscribe` to an `observable`, and store it in a variable. then call `.unsubscribe()` on that variable.

This is a good [read](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/the-best-way-to-unsubscribe-rxjs-observable-in-the-angular-applications-d8f9aa42f6a0)